# How dangerous is CO gas poisoning?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have learned that there are carbon monoxide canisters, and I can't help but feel discomfort at the thought of how morbidly dangerous those will be in a hobbyist home setting. Now let's imagine that someone would mistake it for nitrous oxide or helium and inhale it out of the canister. I imagine that this will be a death sentence, and there is nothing short of a massive blood transfusion that can be done to save that person's life. Is this accurate?

P.S. Please note that I am not planing a murder or a suicide. I just find some of those morbid topics interesting, from time to time, and I think that it is good for us as people, to give some thought, from time to time, to things that can go horribly wrong

Comment: Why would hobbyist need carbon monoxide ? Are you sure it is not carbon dioxide?

Comment: I red that there have been instances of planned group suicides where people intentionally produce CO gas. So I thought - wait a minute, there is probably a more sinister way  of going about that. So after finding out that it is a useful reagent, I thought - nooo, there might be fatalities related to poor practices. And what is more dangerous then an improper home setting

Comment: I am fascinated at what biests chemical engineers contain behind pressure valves

Comment: How dangerous is it? Either you die or you fully recover, afaik. How would you make a transfusion in a time one needs to suffocate? (rhetoric question)

Comment: @Mithoron strictly speaking CO does not suffocate. It damages the blood's ability to transport oxygen and is far slower than suffocation, but more insidious as smaller amounts do the job well. and it isn't always something from which a full recovery is possible.